# How to get BranchesPane in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project opened in IntelliJ and Git is also enabled for the project. What is the issue I am facing is, according to the following image, the red "branch pane" is missing from IDE and the only thing I see is the green area.

And also I see the blue area instead of "Git" it is showing "Version Control". So I need to know how I can get the branch pane back like the attached image.

[image: IntelliJ Idea]

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using?

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers I am using Ultimate 2019.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IntelliJ IDEA is too old, it does not have this feature. To show the branches pane you need at least IntelliJ IDEA version 2020.1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. And also thank you for putting your time to answer this question.